# How To Show Latest Reply in Threaded View in Evolution Mail?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, manjaro, evolution

Evolution mail supports threaded view for email threads. However, it shows the first message received at the "top" in the Messages list. How can I configure the system to show the latest received at the "top" of the conversation thread?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible. Check if the following gsetting is true (which it should be by default)
`gsettings get org.gnome.evolution.mail thread-latest`.
This still show you the first message at the "top" but uses the date of the latest message in a thread for sorting.
See the bug tracker for more details and a workaround which makes the sorting a bit more intuitive: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/-/issues/862#note_758759